# Mathematica Precisions vs Doubles in C/C++

Tags: numerics, precision-and-accuracy, machine-precision

I'm having a bit of an issue regarding numerical precision and I'm not sure how to deal with it.

I have a certain randomly generated matrix, say $M$, that I wish to compute the eigenvalues. The entries of this matrix are real and span many orders of magnitude, from $10^{16}$ down to $10^{-14}$.

I am particularly interested in the case where the smallest eigenvalue is bounded in a region, say $10^{-10}<\lambda_{min}<10^{-9}$. My program then generates some random numbers for the entries of $M$, computes the eigenvalues through

```
EigenValues[N[M,precision]]
```

where 'precision' is specified somewhere before the above evaluation$^a$, and then stores some of the parameters for $M$ that meets the criteria above.

In order to test the numerical precision of my numbers I generated an example instance of $M$, let's call it $M0$. I write down its entries in exact form, i.e.

```
Precision[M0]=Infinity
```

I then compute the eigenvalues with different precisions, namely consider the two cases

```
Eigenvalues[N[M0,MachinePrecision]]
Eigenvalues[N[M0,30]]
```

and test these results against the same computation carried out by a C program.

For a specific matrix $M0$ that I am using for this test I get the following results for its eigenvalues.

- Mathematica With MachinePrecision:
  $$
   1.08568\times 10^{15} \\
   -1.08568\times 10^{15} \\
   2.04979\times 10^{13} \\
   1.98037\times 10^{13} \\
   -1.51195\times 10^{10} \\
   1.51195\times 10^{10} \\
   737.092 \\
   709.496 \\
   -288.09 \\
   287.764 \\
   -0.0527701
  $$
- Mathematica With precision=30:
  $$
   1.08568468076658564504709826065\times 10^{15} \\
   -1.08568468076544177351940777511\times 10^{15} \\
   2.04978825179076415641037942687\times 10^{13} \\
   1.98037159026622180001959563609\times 10^{13} \\
   -1.51195073626019461804045801802\times 10^{10} \\
   1.51195073626019461804034605668\times 10^{10} \\
   737.067283246721413545966471801 \\
   709.473111591071399129829176386 \\
   -288.009491702297922120741501773 \\
   287.845096874967906231858249555 \\
   -\text{1.04616771734909972710824504576458020590918184213753$\grave{ }$30.*${}^{\wedge}$-8}
  $$
- Custom made C code, where the numbers are taken to be Double
  $$
       +2.472\times10^{-10}\\
       +2.878\times10^{+02}\\
       -2.880\times10^{+02}\\
       +7.095\times10^{+02}\\
       +7.371\times10^{+02}\\
       +1.512\times10^{+10}\\
       -1.512\times10^{+10}\\
       +1.980\times10^{+13}\\
       +2.050\times10^{+13}\\
       -1.086\times10^{+15}\\
       +1.086\times10^{+15}
  $$

Now, reading through [Mathematica's documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/MachinePrecisionNumbers.html), I was expecting the custom made code and MachinePrecision to agree since

> The typical arrangement is that all machine‐precision numbers in the Wolfram Language are represented as "double‐precision floating‐point numbers" in the underlying computer system. On most current computers, such numbers contain a total of 64 binary bits, typically yielding 16 decimal digits of mantissa.

And I understand that due to a mantissa of around 16 digits, the first numerical problems would start at around $0.01$, since the biggest number is of order $10^{15}$. This expectation is confirmed by the differences between the numbers obtained within Mathematica with different precisions. But I cannot make sense of differences between the C code and MachinePrecision numbers obtained in Mathematica.

My questions are then:

**What numbers should I trust?**

**Why is MachinePrecision result different than C-code result?**

Notes:

a) 'precision' is used as a defining variable whenever I can set Precision or WorkingPrecision. This includes the RandomReal[] functions calls, N[], etc. A numerical generated matrix $M$ has

```
Precision[M]=precision
```

Comment: "and test these results against the same computation carried out by a C program" <- There are different ways to compute eigenvalues, and they may give different results in precision-sensitive situations.  What does your C program do exactly? Mathematica can also use different algorithms and unfortunately not all of these are fully documented.

Comment: But generally I would trust the values that agree with Mathematica's high precision result.

Comment: You didn't mention what exactly is done in your "custom-made C code", so it's hard to say anything. For instance, unsymmetric matrices whose entries span many orders of magnitude are usually preprocessed by a balancing transformation before being fed to a QR routine, to use a typical workflow example. Did your code do that?

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for your comments! I'm working with other people and I didn't write the C code, but as far as I know it is a C++ code that uses Armadillo package. The matrix is Symmetric, not too big (11x11), with doubles as entries. And I assume it was compiled in a 64bit CPU. The fact that it is Symmetric from the start should make the usage of eigenvalue function straightforward, no? It has been a long time since my Numerical Analysis university course!

Comment: Can you give example matrices?

Comment: You really should have mentioned that it was symmetric to begin with, that's a very important piece of information! The eigenvalue problem is nicer in this case, but if the matrix is graded, one usually does a similarity transformation with permutation matrices so that all the large entries are concentrated around the upper left or lower right, depending on how the subsequent tridiagonalization works. This is a way to preserve significant digits in the tiny eigenvalues. We don't know if the custom code does that.

Comment: I will assume no but I'll comment that point to my collaborator. The testmatrix can be found here https://www.dropbox.com/s/jej34nitwme8wq9/testmatrix.m?dl=0

Comment: @J.M. could you give me a reference highlighting the procedure? It might be easier to explain seeing an algorithm

Comment: The LAPACK manual (and the older manual for EISPACK, as well as the granddaddy *Handbook for Automatic Computation, Volume II: Linear Algebra*) should be usable starting points.

Comment: But I would like to point out that the discrepancy for the lowest eigenvalue among the three routes: precision=30, MachinePrecision, and the C++ code; is orders of magnitude! In the end my concern at this stage is on which method is giving me the correct orders of magnitude.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a long comment really.

Out of curiosity, I compared the result of three packages: Mathematica, MATLAB and [`eig_sym`](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#eig_sym) from Armadillo (compiled on OS X).  You said that your C++ code uses Armadillo.

I get very close but not identical results:

Mathematica `MachinePrecision`:

```
{1.08568*10^15, -1.08568*10^15, 2.04979*10^13, 
 1.98037*10^13, -1.51195*10^10, 
 1.51195*10^10, 737.092, 709.496, -288.09, 287.764, -0.0531685}
```

MATLAB:

```
{1.08568*10^15, -1.08568*10^15, 2.04979*10^13, 
 1.98037*10^13, -1.51195*10^10, 
 1.51195*10^10, 737.092, 709.496, -288.09, 287.764, -0.0531657}
```

Armadillo `eig_sym`:

```
{1.08568*10^15, -1.08568*10^15, 2.04979*10^13, 
 1.98037*10^13, -1.51195*10^10, 
 1.51195*10^10, 737.092, 709.496, -288.089, 287.765, -0.0532012}
```

These are all different form the result obtained with Mathematica arbitrary precision arithmetic with 100 digits, which gives `-1.046*10^-8` for the smallest eigenvalue.

Your main question is: which result can be trusted.  We can try to compute the eigenvectors as well and verify:

```
{val, vec} = Eigensystem[N[mat, 100]];

mat.vec[[-1]]/vec[[-1]]
```

This gives a vector where all entries agree to many digits and they are all `-1.046*10^-8`.

Now let us try machine precision for the eigensystem computation, but use high precision again for the verification:

```
{val, vec} = Eigensystem[N[mat, MachinePrecision]];

v = SetPrecision[vec[[-1]], 100];

mat.v/v

{742.726, 704.17, 
 3.00435*10^8, 48.2152, -129.252, 39.4756, -6.75853*10^-8, \
-2.58842*10^6, 1.96944*10^13, 1.98037*10^13, -1.67772*10^7}
```

Now we don't get the same values.

This indicates that the machine precision result is incorrect, while the high precision result is correct (as one would naively expect).

---

The code I used, for reference:

```
In[2]:= Eigenvalues[N[mat, 100]]

Out[2]= {1.\
0856846807665856450470982606468499998443593068923500101675873225220935\
64695808687498260652176359947*10^15, \
-1.0856846807654417735194077751054318897882403216356104198311574238345\
32051036384281450170890942140023*10^15, 
 2.0497882517907641564103794268674566843581943794938406285013154951144\
39397586760816469279826548743094*10^13, 
 1.9803715902662218000195956360852879283233255266649313821701000225618\
94167023214407217436135853211420*10^13, \
-1.5119507362601946180404580180226453265713175363317940722790080527023\
38252239086243921340499166490296*10^10, 
 1.5119507362601946180403460566794916459982630836031304301486393770875\
41052713765641281269928732700045*10^10, \
737.067283246721413545966471801175928892427820125177205599257512879741\
5217269062183664175848994015722, \
709.473111591071399129829176386128726837373250051028953864335805315683\
3282193626859167101643402616852, \
-288.00949170229792212074150177336349486164509410462852414839291990667\
67324980503281076889597723655422, \
287.845096874967906231858249554911428826683897345958518850569903869812\
2959065307646083681528989497732, \
-1.0461677173490997271082450457645821365852016628481886960614069559648\
94667505277812120367633524821533*10^-8}

In[3]:= Eigenvalues[N[mat]]

Out[3]= {1.08568*10^15, -1.08568*10^15, 2.04979*10^13, 
 1.98037*10^13, -1.51195*10^10, 
 1.51195*10^10, 737.092, 709.496, -288.09, 287.764, -0.0531685}

In[4]:= AddPath["MATLink1Dev"]

In[7]:= << MATLink`

In[8]:= OpenMATLAB[]

In[11]:= Reverse@SortBy[Abs]@Flatten[MFunction["eig"][mat]]

Out[11]= {1.08568*10^15, -1.08568*10^15, 2.04979*10^13, 
 1.98037*10^13, -1.51195*10^10, 
 1.51195*10^10, 737.092, 709.496, -288.09, 287.764, -0.0531657}

In[12]:= << LTemplate`

SetDirectory[$TemporaryDirectory];

In[14]:= tem = LClass["Eig",
   {LFun["eig", {{Real, 2, "Constant"}}, {Real, 1}]}
   ];

code = "
  #undef P

  #include <armadillo>

  struct Eig {
    mma::RealTensorRef eig(mma::RealMatrixRef t) {
        arma::mat m( t.begin(), t.cols(), t.rows() );
        arma::vec ev = eig_sym(m.t());
        return mma::makeVector<double>(ev.size(), ev.memptr());
    }
  };
  ";
Export["Eig.h", code, "String"];

In[40]:= CompileTemplate[tem, 
 "IncludeDirectories" -> {"/opt/local/include"}, 
 "CompileOptions" -> {"-std=c++11", "-mmacosx-version-min=10.11"}, 
 "LibraryDirectories" -> {"/opt/local/lib"}, 
 "Libraries" -> {"armadillo"}]

In[41]:= LoadTemplate[tem]

eig = Make[Eig];

In[45]:= Reverse@SortBy[Abs]@eig@"eig"[mat]

Out[45]= {1.08568*10^15, -1.08568*10^15, 2.04979*10^13, 
 1.98037*10^13, -1.51195*10^10, 
 1.51195*10^10, 737.092, 709.496, -288.089, 287.765, -0.0532012}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer. I just want to cross-check the C++ results myself first before I give you a tick for correct answer :)

Comment: I got quite different results, mainly the lowest eigenvalue I got 1.0785e-06, using eig_sym. Using eig_gen I get -4.130e-08 which again is not compatible. I then decided to implement the check m.vec^T-vec^T.diag(vals) and could see that C and MachinePrecision results are not reliable, while setting precision to rel. high values provides consistent results. Long story short, I'll keep to Mathematica as I can be sure the precision is being tracked correctly. Thank you a lot!

Comment: @romanovzky I don't know much about linear algebra software, but I think that Armadillo's results may be influenced by the underlying BLAS/LAPACK implementations.  I'm on OS X using it's built-in Accelerate framework (the default for Armadillo).  On Linux Armadillo would be using some other BLAS depending on its configuration.